# Настройка серверного оборудования. Поднятие множество изолированных серверов на одном сервере HP Proliant DL

Tags: сервер, сеть, домен, поддомены, hp

Планирую купить сервер HP Proliant DL 560 G8
4 x Intel XEON 10 Core E5-4650 V2 2.40 GHz (SR1AG) 95 W
320GB (40х8GB) DDR3 ECC Registered

Идея заключается в том чтобы поднять 40 независимых серверов (друг с другом взаимодействовать не будут), каждому из них выделить 1 ядро процессора и 8 GB ОЗУ. Каждый из этих серверов должен иметь своё доменное имя.

Вопросы:

1. С помощью чего можно сделать присвоение каждому серверу только 1 ядро и 8 гб озу? Есть ли встроенные утилиты которые это делают или нужны сторонние?
2. Что необходимо для настройки серверов чтобы у каждого был свой айпи и доменное имя?

Заранее благодарен за любые подсказки, которые помогут мне разобраться в этом направлении.

Comment: 1. KVM с любыми фронтэндами, как-то virsh, virt-manager etc.
2. Адреса, выданные провайдером/ами в нужном количестве; домен(ы), вами зарегистрированный(ые) и управляемый(ые).